# Accessing a Single Variable from Another Class (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

So, I'm having trouble figuring out how to best structure my Python code. I have a short program using classes, which I've recreated in an example below:

```
prof1 = Professor()
prof2 = Professor()
professor_list = [prof1, prof2]

class Professor:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.department = ""
    self.course = ""
    self.students = []

class Student:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.activities = []
```

So basically, I have a list of objects which are instances of the `Professor` class. Each Professor object also contains a list of Student objects, each of which is an instance of the `Student` class. I want each Student to also be able to access the `course` variable from its corresponding Professor (the Professor object with that Student in its list), but I wasn't sure what the neatest way to do this would be.

I considered having `Student` inherit from `Professor`, but that seemed sloppy, since I don't actually want to inherit all of the variables and functionality from `Professor`. For example, Professor's department variable has nothing to do with a Student object, and I don't want Students to have a department attribute. Also, Student isn't a sub-type of Professor, which is what I would associate with inheritance.

I also thought of manually adding the course information to each Student as an attribute, but that didn't seem right either. In the structure I want, the course would be a unique attribute of the Professor, and the various students would be associated with the Professor. All the students that would need to access the course variable are in the Professor's student list - so shouldn't there be a neater way of allowing them to use it than adding it manually to each student?

Here's one more idea: I might include a reference to the corresponding `Professor` class in each `Student`, and access the variable that way. Would this be bad practice?

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go the route of the reference to the `Professor`, but I think the easiest way would be to create an `add_student` method which adds the `Student` to the corresponding `Professor`'s list, as well as marks the course on the `Student`, so you don't have to do this manually and you can avoid a circular reference (which also is unnecessary because if you're marking the `Professor` reference on the `Student` just to get the `course` attribute, then you may as well just mark the `course` attribute directly):

```
class Professor:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.department = ""
    self.course = ""
    self.students = []

  def add_student(self, student):
    self.students.append(student)
    student.course = self.course

class Student:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.activities = []
    self.course = None
```

Alternatively, you could add a method to the `Professor` which checks if the `Student` belongs to it and use that to get the course:

```
prof1 = Professor()
prof2 = Professor()
professor_list = [prof1, prof2]

class Professor:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.department = ""
    self.course = ""
    self.students = []

  def teaches(self, student):
    return student in self.students

class Student:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.activities = []

  def get_course(self, professors):
    for professor in professors:
      if professor.teaches(self):
        return professor.course

    return None
```